# Magento - Coupon to be applied after status change and not on order place

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to basically apply coupon to an order only after its status changes to processing. After debugging I have come to know that on `sales_order_place_after` event an observer is called in file `app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Observer.php` with function `sales_order_afterPlace`.

I want to override this observer to add a condition to check the status of the order and only then proceed ahead with coupon.

Additionally, I want to override the `config.xml` to use event order status change or order save event instead of order place event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is how i worked it out.

In my `etc/modules/Namespace_Package.xml` I added a depends tag as:

```
<depends>
  <Mage_SalesRule/>
</depends>
```

and in my `config.xml` I added the below code:

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <salesrule>
                <type>disabled</type>
            </salesrule>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
    <sales_order_save_after>
        <observers>
            <salesrule>
                <class>salesrule/observer</class>
                <method>sales_order_afterPlace</method>
            </salesrule>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
```

and in module tag I had to override the observer this way:

```
<models>
    <modulename>
        <class>Namespace_Package_Model</class>
    </modulename>
    <salesrule>
        <rewrite>
           <observer>Namespace_Package_Model_Salesrule_Observer</observer>
        </rewrite>
    </salesrule>
</models>
```